# ssh to different network inteface?

Tags: networking, ssh

I don't know the right vocabulary to more succinctly ask this question or to search for duplicates:  Someone who knows what I'm trying to ask, please edit the title of this post to be more accurate.

There's a server I'm working on.  It is set up as a proxy server among other things.  The computer I'm working from is connecting wirelessly directly to the DSL modem that the server also connects to.  There is a web-GUI tool (for managing the shared printers) that is available from the server's other network interface.

That is to say, the server has two network interfaces - one that is etho0 (IP address of 10.0.0.3) and one that is eht2 (IP address 192.168.0.1).  The laptop I'm working on is on the 10.0.* network.   I'm trying to access 192.168.0.1:631.  I can ssh to the server.

Is there a way I can use ssh to translate connect to 192.168.0.1:631 from the 10.0.* side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward a remote port to a local port via SSH:

> ```
>  -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
> ```
>
> Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side. This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address. Whenever a connection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is made to host port hostport from the remote machine.

So, something like:

```
ssh -L 1631:192.168.0.1:631 10.0.0.3
```

Now connect to `localhost:1631`.

Additionally, you can use the `-fN` option to send this connection to the background.

Comment: That did it.   For posterity, `ssh -L 1631:192.168.0.1:631 username@10.0.0.3`   BTW, is port forwarding what this is called?

Comment: @DavidOneill Yes, as far as I know. There are two other ways to do it: using the `-R` option, which works just like -L except that the port is allocated on the remote end (ie, reverse), and the `-D` option, which I don't know well.